# AJAX script manager within a masterpage in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

I'm using Ajax in page which is under a masterpage.
I have a problem with the location of the script manager. I don't want the script manager to be for all the pages, just for one.

this is the master page :

```
         <div>

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            </div>
```

and this is the page which I want to add the script manager to it

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="120"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:NumericUpDownExtender
        ID="NumericUpDownExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" Maximum="9" Minimum="1" Width="120">
    </asp:NumericUpDownExtender>
</asp:Content>
```

When I run it this problem occuer:" Control 'ContentPlaceHolder1_ScriptManager1' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."

So I read on the internet that I have to put the content in the master page inside a form tag like this :

```
          <div>
            <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 25px">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </form>
            </div>
```

but when I do this another problem occures: 
"A page can have only one server-side Form tag."

I have no Idea what to do, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net you are not allowed to have more form tags. Instead of having many forms you have only one big form that will contain all your content.

In Master:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat=server>

   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />

   </form>
</body>
```

In ContentPlaceHolder:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    'your code here'
</asp:Content>
```

Use search in all files to check if you have more than one form tag.

Comment: I did exactly what you write(instead of ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" I replaced it in ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent") And the same problem occures : "A page can have only one server-side Form tag."

Comment: The problem was not the naming of the ContentPlaceHolder. The problem is that you had more than one form, and Asp.net WebForms doesn't allow you to have more than one form tag in your page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because I had another form in this page. But not a form inside a form, Why can't I have more than one form In a master page ?

Answer (score 0):

Site master page:

```
   <form runat="server">
             <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
                 <Scripts>
                  
                     <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                     <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" Path="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js" />
                   <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" Path="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" />
                  <asp:ScriptReference  Path="~/Scripts/YourScript.js" />
</Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" id="about" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

These are the Aspx page code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div runat=server id=subMenus></div>
</asp:Content>
```

And the JS file:

```
$('#about').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $('#MainContent_subMenus').load('let.aspx');
        
    });
```

So the jquery 'load' an ajax call.This function give through the aspx file for the <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" to *id=subMenus* div

> P.S:

*BE careful the ID The master page give "MainContent_" tag before almost every element.*

**It works for me.
I hope this is helps for you.**

Answer (score -1):

Put your `script manager` inside `contentplace holder`.

Comment: when I do it it tells me "The control with ID 'NumericUpDownExtender1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it."